# DateTime format yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

How can I convert a datetime in this format `27/10/2014 00:00:00` to `2014-10-27T00:00:00`
 I've tried `ToUniversalTime but it didnWt work.

```
config.PreferredStartDate = pstnGetWorkingDayInfoResponse.Date.ToUniversalTime();
```

Both Dates here are DateTime variables

I've also tried:

```
config.PreferredStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(pstnGetWorkingDayInfoResponse.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: If they are both date times then why is there a conversion needed? do you mean you want to display the output differently?

Comment: "Didn't work" is not an error description we can help you with. State what you did, what happened when you did it and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: DateTime does *not* have a format. `ToUniversalTime` deals with timezones which is not what you asked (I think). Are you trying to convert the date to a string somewhere else and don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both variables are dates, then the question doesn't make any sense - a date isn't stored in any particular "format", any date can be displayed on a screen in any format.

If you want to display it in a different way, then this is the same format as for XML. So an easy way to do this is to use the built-in XML conversion methods, in this case [`XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds88xsz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Xml;
...
config.PreferredStartDate = XmlConvert.ToString(pstnGetWorkingDayInfoResponse.Date);
```

Comment: The requested format is the [sortable standard pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx). You can just write `myDate.ToString("s")` instead of using XmlConvert

Answer (score 8):

Check this :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String strDate="";
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");   // 07/21/2007 
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");   //Saturday, 21 July 2007
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 14:58
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 03:00 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 5:01 
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 3:03 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:04:10
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"); // 07/21/2007 15:05
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); // 07/21/2007 03:06 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"); // 07/21/2007 15:07
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"); // 07/21/2007 3:07 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // 07/21/2007 15:09:29
strDate = dt.ToString("MMMM dd"); // July 21
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK"); // 2007-07-21T15:11:19.1250000+05:30    
strDate = dt.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"); // Sat, 21 Jul 2007 15:12:16 GMT
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"); // 2007-07-21T15:12:57
strDate = dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 15:14
strDate = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 03:14 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 5:15
strDate = dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 3:16 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // 15:16:29
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"); // 2007-07-21 15:17:20Z
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:17:58
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy MMMM"); // 2007 July
```

I found it from [Formats for DateTime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 10, 27, 0, 0, 0);
string strDate = date.ToString(myDTFI.SortableDateTimePattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

As M.Azad answered above try

```
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"); // 2007-07-21T15:12:57
```

or in your case it maybe:

```
PreferredStartDateToString = pstnGetWorkingDayInfoResponse.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: Apparently (from the sample code) `PreferredStartDate`  has type DateTime, so setting it to a string will not work

Comment: Thank you @HansKesting, I agree. DateTime does not have a format. I am assuming that the author was trying to convert the date to a string to use or show somewhere